# Is it possible to call a function from another class in the kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a popup window that I created with a class. In this popup, I have 2 buttons. Depending on the button you press, it has to call a function which is in the main class.

If you call a function in the kv file with "on_release:" which is in the same class, you write "root....()". What should I write if I want to call one of the functions from another class?

Thank you

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: if you make a popup and you want to close it, you write "on_release: root.dismiss()". The problem is that before closing it, I need to set a value in an array. So I need to call a function in another class. I just want to know what would be the command to call a function from another class (let's say "Main"). I thought it was "Main.function()" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well what about OtherClass.function()?

Comment: It says: name 'OtherClass' in not defined. Of course, I used the real class name, not 'OtherClass'

Comment: @Laurent provide a [MRE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `kv` you can reference `app`, `self`, or `root`. See [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords). So, if you have a reference to `OtherClass` in any of those, you can use that reference in `kv`. For example, if in your `App` class you include a line:

```
self.otherClassRef = OtherClass()
```

then in your `kv` you can use

```
on_release: app.otherClassRef.someMethod()
```

Regardless, you must have a reference to an instance of `OtherClass` to access instance methods.

You can access static methods using

```
on_release: OtherClass.someStaticMethod()
```

or an instance method using

```
on_release: OtherClass().someMethod()
```

but you will likely need to import `OtherClass` in your `kv`. Something like

```
#:import OtherClass OtherClassFileName.OtherClass
```

Note that if you do `OtherClass().someMethod()` you are creating a new instance of `OtherClass`, not using any currently existing instance.

Comment: Thank you so much John. Exactly what I needed!